# Django - Giving "a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'" error while trying to create manual jwt token function

Tags: python, django, jwt

I need to create custom JWT token creator. When I want to test it with dump data it gives this error. All I need is return a json web token. I am new to Django and Python. I partially understand the problem but can't relate. I'm struggling with data types while working on them. I tried to convert token variable into different data type but didn't work.

https://dpaste.com/B9K9KWP27

Here is my codes

```
def base64url_decode(input: Union[str, bytes]) -> bytes:
    if isinstance(input, str):
        input = input.encode("ascii")

    rem = len(input) % 4

    if rem > 0:
        input += b"=" * (4 - rem)

    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input)


def base64url_encode(input: bytes) -> bytes:
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(input).replace(b"=", b"")


def jwt_creator(expiration, userid, userrole):
    header = {
        "alg": "HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
    payload = {'expired': expiration,
               'userid': userid,
               'userrole': userrole
               }
    secret_key = secrets.token_hex(32)
    userauth =User_Tokensec(iduser_tokensec=userid, key=secret_key, personal_id=Personal.objects.get(id=userid))
    userauth.save()

    total_params = base64url_encode(header) + '.' + base64url_encode(payload)
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key, total_params, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    token = total_params + '.' + base64url_encode(signature)
    context3 = {'jwt': token, 'title': 'jwtt'}
    return context3


def jwt_decoder(jwt):

    input = jwt.split(".")
    payload = base64url_decode(input[1])
    secret_key = User_Tokensec(personal_id=payload['userid']) 

    header = {
        "alg": "HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }

    total_params = base64url_encode(header) + '.' + base64url_encode(payload)
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key, total_params, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    token = total_params + '.' + base64url_encode(signature)
    if signature == input[2]:
        output = (True, token[1])
        return output
    else:
        return False
```

This is views.py

```
def index(request):
    test = generateJWT.jwt_creator(60, 1, 2)

    return render(request, 'Login.html')

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/

Django Version: 3.2.4
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['DataCollector.apps.DatacollectorConfig',
 'RemoteManager.apps.RemotemanagerConfig',
 'DataDispatcher.apps.DatadispatcherConfig',
 'LocalAuth.apps.LocalauthConfig',
 'LocalManager.apps.LocalmanagerConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/gokselozgur/myProjects/eybt-cloned/e-ybt-backend/django/eYBT/LocalAuth/views.py", line 9, in index
    test = generateJWT.jwt_creator(60, 1, 2)
  File "/Users/gokselozgur/myProjects/eybt-cloned/e-ybt-backend/django/eYBT/RemoteManager/generateJWT.py", line 38, in jwt_creator
    total_params = base64url_encode(header) + '.' + base64url_encode(payload)
  File "/Users/gokselozgur/myProjects/eybt-cloned/e-ybt-backend/django/eYBT/RemoteManager/generateJWT.py", line 22, in base64url_encode
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(input).replace(b"=", b"")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 118, in urlsafe_b64encode
    return b64encode(s).translate(_urlsafe_encode_translation)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/v1/auth/
Exception Value: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'
```

Comment: Please include the traceback in the question itself!

Comment: I added the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full code of jwt generator and decoder in python for who does not want to install full package just for two operation. You can save key into related user model if you want as I did.

```
def base64url_decode(input):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input+'==')

def base64url_encode(input):
    stringAsBytes = input.encode('ascii')
    stringAsBase64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(stringAsBytes).decode('utf-8').replace('=','')
    return stringAsBase64 


def jwt_creator(expiration, userid, userrole):
    header = {
        "alg": "HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
    payload = {'expired': expiration,
               'userid': userid,
               'userrole': userrole
               }
    secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)    
    User_Tokensec.objects.update_or_create(personal=Personal.objects.get(id=userid),defaults = {'key':secret_key})    
    total_params = str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(header))) + '.' + str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(payload)))
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), total_params.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    token = total_params + '.' + str(base64url_encode(signature))
    return token


def jwt_decoder(jwt):
    input = jwt.split(".")    
    decodedpayload = base64url_decode( input[1] ).decode()    
    payload = json.loads(decodedpayload)    
    secret_key = User_Tokensec.objects.get( personal = int(payload['userid'])).key
    header = {
        "alg": "HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
    total_params = str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(header))) + '.' + str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(payload)))
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), total_params.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()   
    if str(base64url_encode(signature)) == input[2]:
        output = (True, input[1],payload)
        return output
    else:
        return False
```

The model.

```
class UserToken (models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    createdat = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    personal = models.OneToOneField(Personal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your jwt_creator method, you need to cast header and payload (that are dict type) to string. Also you need to convert it to bytes because Python3 default encoding is utf-8.

```
    total_params = base64url_encode(str(header)) + '.' + base64url_encode(str(payload))
    signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, 'utf-8'), total_params, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    token = bytes(total_params + '.' + base64url_encode(signature))
```

Comment: It gives that error now "can't concat str to bytes"

Comment: Right, you can't concat after the cast. Check now, I modified the answer. Note that if 'secret_key' is type bytes you can remove the cast in the second line.